# ng-change on checkbox requires 2 clicks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a controller getting a list of users and a view listing them, along with a checkbox for displaying and setting whether they are active...

```
.controller('StaffCtrl', ['StaffService', function(StaffService) {
  var self = this;
  self.staff = StaffService.query();
  self.activeUpdate = function(person){
    StaffService.update({id:person.id}, person);
  };
}]);

<tr ng-repeat="person in staffCtrl.staff">
  <td>{{ person.name_full }} </td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="person.active" ng-model="person.active" ng-change="staffCtrl.activeUpdate(person)" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"></td>
</tr>
```

Clicking the checkbox once triggers `activeUpdate`, the async call is made and the user updated, but within the view the check mark itself doesn't disappear from the checkbox (in latest Chrome and Firefox). If I click it again now the check mark disappears and `activeUpdate` isn't called. If I click once more the check reappears and the call gets made all at the same time, always only when adding the check, removing it consistently takes 2 clicks!

What am I doing wrong?

Update: Sample JSON for the staff list (using curl to query the REST api...)

```
[
    {
        "active": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name_first": "Ed",
        "name_full": "Tech, Ed",
        "name_last": "Tech",
        "name_middle": null,
        "uri": "/sips/api/staff/1",
        "username": "admin"
    },
    {
        "active": 1,
        "id": 252,
        "name_first": "test",
        "name_full": "aatest, test",
        "name_last": "aatest",
        "name_middle": "something",
        "uri": "/sips/api/staff/252",
        "username": "testteacher"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Dont use `ng-checked` along with `ng-model` - the model will take care of updating the checkbox.

Comment: If I take out the `ng-checked` then the checkboxes aren't set correctly initially, they are all empty.

Comment: Can you set up a plunker or fiddle showing this?  If you use both, Angular may be updating it twice, you should only use one.  You probably want to use `ng-model`, are you sure the value you initially set is appropriate for the checkbox model?  Also show the JSON for a sample person.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `ng-checked` and `ng-model` together can conflict, they both want to set the actual checked state of the checkbox.  Second, `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` seem to only work with strings.  So when you are clicking to set the value, it changes `person.active` from the number 1 to the string `'1'`.  That is also what causes the unchecking problem, the string "0" is a `true` value so `ng-checked` thinks the box should be checked but `ng-model` does not.

And since `ngTrueValue` only accepts constant expressions, I don't see an easy way to get it to do what you want with numbers for `active`. ([Angular Source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L885))

You might be able to skip using `ngModel` and instead use `ngChecked` for display and `ngClick` to update your property with a method [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQlqcWROGfowayXWqS5T?p=preview):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="person.active" 
       ng-click="updateActive(person)"</input>
```

JS:

```
self.updateActive = function(person) {
  console.dir(person);
  person.active = 1 - person.active;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, switching the api to return a string for `person.active` fixed it!

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, Angular works best (in this context) if you forget true, false, 0 and 1 and just think two strings '0' and '1' - though once you realise it works ok with strings, you could use anything I guess 'yes/no' 'true/false'

You need to use just and exactly this:

```
ng-model = "object.property"
ng-true=value="'1'" // note the string
ng-false-value = "'0'"
ng-checked = "object.property=='1'"
```

and then it works perfectly, no other work arounds needed.
Use ng-change for a notify if you need it but don't use it to change the state of object.property or there will, of course, be conflicts

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change like below and  rest model will do automatically.
you also don't need to put ng-checked as you are already using ng-model.

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="person.active" ng-change="staffCtrl.activeUpdate(person)" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'">
```